# pymongo - find function is very slow

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

i am working with mongodb cloud (pymongo driver) and i have there a collection of 1000 documents (200mb overall).

Each document is as follows:

```
{"_id": 1,
 "a": oneLineDict, #Object
 "b": { #Object
     "1": ListOfHundredsSmallDicts1, #Array of Objects
     "2": ListOfHundredsSmallDicts2,
     ...,
     "up to 15": ListOfHundredsSmallDicts15},
 "_id":2, #doc 2
 }
```

My code:

```
BIG_LIST = mycol.find({"_id": {"$gte": 100, "$lte": 199}})
start_time = time.time()
for api in BIG_LIST:
    print(int(time.time() - start_time))
    break #just for this test
    # only the first loop takes so long. The rest appear immediately.
    # but every 100 it stop for few minutes.

>>> 65
```

It takes over a minute to run this single line `for api in BIG_LIST`!
Is there any way i can make it any faster?

```
print(mycol.find({"_id": {"$gte": first, "$lte": last}}).explain())
>>> {'queryPlanner': {'plannerVersion': 1, 'namespace': 'mydatabase.mycollection', 'indexFilterSet': False, 'parsedQuery': {'$and': [{'_id': {'$lte': 100}}, {'_id': {'$gte': 199}}]}, 'winningPlan': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'indexName': '_id_', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'_id': []}, 'isUnique': True, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'_id': ['[100, 199]']}}}, 'rejectedPlans': []}, 'executionStats': {'executionSuccess': True, 'nReturned': 100, 'executionTimeMillis': 0, 'totalKeysExamined': 100, 'totalDocsExamined': 100, 'executionStages': {'stage': 'FETCH', 'nReturned': 100, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0, 'works': 101, 'advanced': 100, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 0, 'restoreState': 0, 'isEOF': 1, 'docsExamined': 100, 'alreadyHasObj': 0, 'inputStage': {'stage': 'IXSCAN', 'nReturned': 100, 'executionTimeMillisEstimate': 0, 'works': 101, 'advanced': 100, 'needTime': 0, 'needYield': 0, 'saveState': 0, 'restoreState': 0, 'isEOF': 1, 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'indexName': '_id_', 'isMultiKey': False, 'multiKeyPaths': {'_id': []}, 'isUnique': True, 'isSparse': False, 'isPartial': False, 'indexVersion': 2, 'direction': 'forward', 'indexBounds': {'_id': ['[100, 199]']}, 'keysExamined': 100, 'seeks': 1, 'dupsTested': 0, 'dupsDropped': 0}}, 'allPlansExecution': []}, 'serverInfo': {'host': '*****', 'port': ****, 'version': '4.2.6', 'gitVersion': '***'}, 'ok': 1.0, '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1588233776, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'*****', 'keyId': ***}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1588233776, 1)}
(5 seconds)
```

I have tried to run it on my computer, and on heroku cloud (which was a little faster, but not significantly))
Thanks

Comment: can you put your schema here?, how you indexing your schema?

Comment: @a_m_dev i added the schema now.
I did not create a special index, I read that the default index is "_id"

Comment: no the Schema of the collection i meant!, you can read this article to get some points on how to put index on your collection to perform fast queries on your collection https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-create-an-index-for-a-mongodb-collection-in-python-371

Comment: @a_m_dev the "_id" index isn't good enough?

Comment: @akiva Please run the `explain` on the `find` query and post the results. The explain generates a query plan. You can run it from the PyMongo or _mongo shell_; e.g., from PyMongo: `collection.find(<your condition>).explain()`

Comment: I'm going to hazard it's not an index issue but a slow connection issue; mongo gets data in batches of 100 records so this would explain the effect being seen.

Comment: @prasad_ Done. i edited my Q with the results.

Comment: @BellyBuster I have tried to run it on my computer, and on heroku cloud (which was a little faster, but not significantly)) Thanks

Comment: By "on my computer" do you mean still connecting to mongodb cloud?

Comment: @BellyBuster yeah

Comment: @akiva The query planner's says that it is using the index on `_id` field. The  `executionStats` shows: `"executionStats":{ "executionSuccess":True,      "nReturned":100, "executionTimeMillis":0, "totalKeysExamined":100,
 "totalDocsExamined":100,`. The issue might not be the query condition (_see "executionTimeMillis":0_). QUESTIONS: What are the fields you want to use from your query? What is it you want to do with the queried data?

Comment: @prasad_ i need 1-2 values from `a`, and few values from each line of each array in `b`

Comment: Can you be more specific about the `b`, please.

Comment: When it runs slowly, it should result in an entry in the mongod log, does that provide any information?

Comment: @akiva Difficult to understand the nested for-loops you had posted,

Comment: @prasad_ yeah i know, the comments format won't let me to do it in the right way. screenshot of the original code: http://prntscr.com/s8ildl .

Comment: @Joe i am still trying to find those logs. no luck yet.

Comment: The `"executionTimeMillis":0` says the query completed nearly instantaneously, which makes sense give this is a query on the `_id` which is always indexed. I would look outside mongodb for the cause of your slow down. Something else in your code is creating delays.

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole the `explain()` function explaining the `fine` line, but as seen in the code the problem is in the loop ("converting" the curser). I have tried the very same loop with local json files (same data) on my computer, and it finished instantaneously.

Comment: That happens because converting the cursor incurs a network round trip for each execution of `getmore` as your program consumes the results of the cursor. For a very large result set that can result in lots of documents. To reduce the traffic consider use a projection (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) to reduce the size of the result documents.